# How does Ubuntu 14.04 achieve persistent eth* interfaces?

Tags: ubuntu, udev, network-interface

Trying to upgrade `udev` to 197+ on my LFS system, I've come across a problem that old persistent network interface names scheme is [no longer supported](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).

Before trying to go on with the new suggested scheme I wondered how it's done in Ubuntu, and launched its LiveCD in QEMU with two NICs. I've discovered that the interfaces are still `eth0` and `eth1`, not anything like `enp3s0` which would be under new scheme. Looking further, I noticed that there's still `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file which seems to be the same as for pre-197 `udev`.

What does this mean? Does Ubuntu somehow work around the issue and still implement renaming inside eth-namespace? Or does it hack the `udev` to regain support for this? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: This may be better answered at AskUbuntu.com, which is another sub-site of StackExchange.com

Comment: @0xSheepdog I considered this, but in my experience most of the people there are not too deep-inside-system oriented.

Comment: @0xSheepdog Ubuntu questions are fine here and the OP is right that this community is probably better placed to answer this particular one.

Comment: @Ruslan excellent! Not everyone realizes there is an Ubuntu specific SE site; but as you say, sometimes the distro in question isn't central to the help they need. I was simply making sure you knew.

Comment: A natural place to start seems `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha there's nothing in `/etc/udev/rules.d` other than `75-persistent-net.rules` and `README` (which mentions nothing relevant).